# Can't change permissions on a folder on HDFS. Nothing is printed as a reason why.

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hdfs

We cannot change permissions of a single folder on HDFS.  We can change permissions of all the other folders no problem.  Except this one folder.  Current permissions are:

```
drwxrwx--x   - app app          0 2017-03-28 14:29 /app/drops
```

None of these work to change the permission and nothing is printed, not even a permission denied is printed:

```
root@ss01nn01 # hdfs dfs -setfacl -m other::r-x /app/drops
root@ss01nn01 # hdfs dfs -chmod 775 /app/drops
```

We're using the Cloudera line of products.  I've enabled more debugging in HDFS via Cloudera Manager, but still nothing.  How could I debug this further?

Cheers,

Comment: Have you logged a support case with Cloudera? We recently had some weird permission issues with HDFS directories as well and the only resolution was to restart the cluster. Similar situation to yours where it was only happening on one directory and all others were working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

`sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -chmod 775 /app/drops`

Comment: I tried just now.  No effect.  Would at least like to get a way to find out why none of these commands are working.

Comment: Btw, I don't have sentry enabled.